# twitter api how to start

Tags: api, twitter

is any simple docs about api? i looked on site dev.twitter.com but there nothing clear for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a v. simple tutorial. http://www.webmonkey.com/2010/02/get_started_with_the_twitter_api/